# Копирования компонента mesh

Tags: unity3d

Как можно объекту1 присвоить меш либо компонент Mesh объекта2?
Например: есть Куб и Сфера, в редакторе можно сделать Copy Component и из Куба будет Сфера, но как такое же сделать скриптом?

Comment: Похожий вопрос уже задавался, но автор ответа упорно не желает исправить ошибку - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879243/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-unity/879244#comment1429874_879244.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью обычного копирования ссылки из компонента, конечно же :)
За отрисовку объекта в пространстве отвечает компонент [MeshRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-MeshRenderer.html). Если коротко - он знает КАК нужно рисовать те данные, которые передаются ему из компонента [MeshFilter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-MeshFilter.html).

Другими словами, ЧТО будет рисовать `MeshRenderer` зависит от того, что помещено в поле `Mesh` компонента `MeshFilter`. Соответственно ваша цель получить ссылку на компонент `MeshFilter` нужного объекта и поместить в его поле .mesh ссылку на нужный вам меш :)

Банальный код для примера:

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject _cube;

[SerializeField]
GameObject _sphere;

private void Start()
{
    var cubeFilter = _cube.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    var sphereFilter = _sphere.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

    sphereFilter.mesh = cubeFilter.mesh;
}
```

Можно вообще сразу дать ссылки на компоненты `MeshFilter`, а не на объекты.

Однако, не забывайте, что `MeshFilter` отвечает только за МОДЕЛЬ для отрисовки. Материалы, которые при этом будут использоваться находятся в компоненте `MeshRenderer`. Поэтому, если вам нужно менять и материалы - не забудьте подобным же образом скопировать и их :)

Comment: спасибо, но еще вопрос, как скопировать компонент? к примеру rigidbody?

Comment: @k0vpack, так может есть смысл создать префаб и уже потом размещать его копии? :)

Comment: не всегда это возможно, нужно же измененный компонент копировать

Comment: @k0vpack, либо создавайте отдельный скрипт для каждого типа компонента, либо используйте рефлексию. Я уже скинул ссылку на схожий вопрос в комментариях под вашим вопросом.